# Powershell's Invoke-WebRequest RawContentLength vs Content.Length

Tags: powershell, http

I'm using Powershell 5. I noticed an odd behavior in Invoke-WebRequest executed with GET method against html pages and files. An example could be the following code:

```
$test1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://stackoverflow.com/' -Method Get
Write-Host "RawContentLength: $($test1.RawContentLength) bytes, ContentLength: $($test1.Content.Length) bytes"
```

That gets me "RawContentLength: 250286 bytes, ContentLength: 250250 bytes". I thought the difference was due to the fact RawContent contains response headers and body, while Content contains only body. But then I tried the same code against a file:

```
$test2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/hannah-glasses-310th-birthday-5894265455509504-2x.jpg' -Method Get
Write-Host "RawContentLength: $($test2.RawContentLength) bytes, ContentLength: $($test2.Content.Length) bytes"
```

And it produced "RawContentLength: 405686 bytes, ContentLength: 405686 bytes"!

How come RawContentLength and Content.Length are identical when it's a file but different when it's a webpage?

Comment: Javascript maybe? I think the Content-Length header is served by the page, but RawContentLength may be calculated by the IE engine (which a lot of these cmdlets depend on).  [Here's the RFC on the matter](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I tried $test1.Headers['Content-Length'] on https://stackoverflow.com/, and it gave me 251249 (which is equal to neither $test1.RawContentLength nor $test1.Content.Length). O_o

Comment: Probably has to do with encoding based on your console